# Where can I get a vault access card?

Tags: invisible-inc

In my campaign, I keep seeing missions that say I need to bring a vault access card. So far I haven't found any though. Where can they be obtained?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most common place to find a vault access card is to complete a **Chief Financial Suite** mission and successfully obtain the code from the financial executive.

On one occasion I was sold one by **Monst3r** between missions, but this has only happened the once so seems to be pretty rare.